# Dart null safety and parsing JSON to models with json_serializable

Tags: dart, json-serializable

I have a very general question after almost one week of playing around with various tools to de-serialize JSON to Dart and being very frustrated about **null safety**. The `json_serializable` package which generates `.fromJson` and `.toJson` messages should care about NULL values. But I could not make that work at all! So the one million dollar question is:

**Do I have to declare ALL properties of a model as NULLABLE (with a ? e.g. `String? myString`)** if there is *any chance* that the property may be **missing or NULL** in the returned JSON ??

When I do NOT declare such members as NULLABLE, I always get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

These errors always occur in the **generated `FromJson` methods**. Here is a sample JSON which causes the problem:

```
  "responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "500",
    "message": "This is a test message",
    "errors": [
      {
        "errorCode": "300",
        "fieldName": "a field name",
        "message": "a message",
        "meta": {
          "a key": "a value"
        }
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "some field": "some value"
    }
  }
```

The **`errors`** array contains an array of `error objects` which itself may or may not contain an array of `key value pairs` (`meta`). If there are **NO** errors, the `errors` array is **not submitted** as shown here:

```
"responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "500",
    "message": "This is a test message",
    "meta": {
      "some field": "some value"
    }
```

In such a case the **generated DART code crashes** as shown below:

```
ResponseStatus _$ResponseStatusFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    ResponseStatus(
      errorCode: json['errorCode'] as String? ?? '',
      message: json['message'] as String? ?? '',
      stackTrace: json['stackTrace'] as String? ?? '',
    )
      ..errors = (json['errors'] as List<dynamic>)  // <<==== This is crashing if errors is not in the returned JSON
          .map((e) => ResponseError.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList()
      ..meta = Map<String, String>.from(json['meta'] as Map);
```

The model class I created looks as follows:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ResponseStatus extends Equatable {
  late final String errorCode;
  late final String message;
  late final String stackTrace;
  late final List<ResponseError> errors;
  late final Map<String, String> meta;


  ResponseStatus({this.errorCode = '', this.message = '', this.stackTrace = ''}) {
    this.errors = [];
    this.meta = Map();
  }

  factory ResponseStatus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ResponseStatusFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ResponseStatusToJson(this);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [errorCode, message, stackTrace, errors, meta];

}
```

I created a default constructor which initializes all the members (which are NON-nullable) with a value.

If I have to declare all model members as `nullable` this would be unusable since in my flutter widgets I would have to write thousands of `if statements` to check if a member is null. I think *to avoid this was ONE of the ideas behind sound null safety*.

I am curious to learn if this is a bug or how I get this thing working!

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. If data is not given, a crash must occur, because a non-nullable variable can *never* have a `null` value.

You can, however, use a custom deserialisation function to handle this case:

```dart
@JsonKey(fromJson: optionalErrorListFromJson)
late final List<ResponseError> errors;
```

```dart
List<ResponseError> optionalErrorListFromJson(List<dynamic>? errors) {
  if (errors == null) return const [];
  return errors
      .map((e) => ResponseError.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList(growable: false)
}
```